# how to display image with db stored path

Tags: php, image, url, laravel-5

I am creating a tool  in which user uploads an image or gives an external link of image. so I am storing that image url in my database. 
if a user uploads image then I am storing full path of the file 
**eg:**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\project\public\upload/1571149288.jpg
```

and if the user is giving me an image url

**eg:**

```
https://example.com/images/ask1571149288e.jpg.
```

I am storing this full path, in next screen i need to display last three images that user uploaded, in any using db stored path,

**Contoller**

```
$previousUpload = DB::table('background_trimmer')->where('user_id',1)->limit(3)->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();

    return view('user.clippingMagic.upload', array('previousUpload'=>$previousUpload));
```

**Blade View**

```
    <div id="recent-images" class="mt-3">
     @foreach ($previousUpload as $recentImage)
         <div class="recentimages">
             <img src="..\{{$recentImage->image_title}}" alt="image recent" />        

        </div>
      </div>
 @endforeach
</div>
```

getting **404** for image 
and the image src is now
=> `http://127.0.0.1:8000/C:\xampp\htdocs\New folder\marketermagic\public\upload/1571206254images.jpg`

**what i want it**

```
C:\xampp\htdocs\New folder\marketermagic\public\upload/1571206254images.jpg
```

if i hit `C:\xampp\htdocs\New folder\marketermagic\public\upload/1571206254images.jpg` this url in a browser tab i have the image.
as i have stored the full path of image so i dont need to have a base url any anthing to be added by laravel, it should take my url as it is.
thanks for any help

Comment: no this does not resolve my problem and its not like mine as the answer u suggested

Comment: You have to check [Laravel Displaying image from database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28563018/laravel-displaying-image-from-database)

Comment: I tried this one too, {{ asset('uploads/appsetting/' . $page->image) }} as i have full path so nothing to do with asset(); image could be a third party url

Answer (score 0):

## Case Study :

You have two options:

1. User can upload image
2. Or s/he can input external image link.

What you have to do :

1. IF user upload image then make a public browsable url of you internal script. Like user upload abc.png image you should make a public browsable url of that image. Say how ? just add `base url + upload folder path + image name` very simple steps. Final output should look like this : `http://example.com/YOUR_ASSETS_PATH/abc.png` and store it to DB.
2. IF user input external url just save it to DB.

VIEW:
`<img src="{{$recentImage->image_path}}" alt="image recent" />`

#### Thats it !

Comment: as of now, I have stored 'C:\xampp\htdocs\New folder\marketermagic\public\upload/1571206254images.jpg' then it should display the image